# Visitor-Pattern in C++ in a Header-Only Environment

Tags: c++, oop, header-only

I've currently trouble implementing the [Visitor-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in a Header-Only library in C++.

Consider following class which should support being visited by a visitor (no interface for simplicity reasions):

```
class Acceptor
{
    void accept(Visitor* v)
    {
        v->visit(this);
    }
};
```

Here is the interface for the visitors:

```
class Visitor
{
    virtual void visit(Acceptor* t) = 0;
};
```

In a Header-Only lib, Acceptor.hpp must include Visitor.hpp and Visitor.hpp must include Acceptor.hpp. Since both headers are protected by [Include-Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), the later one will fail. Using forward declarations won't solve the problem, too.

Comment: For `Visitor` an incomplete type of `Acceptor` (aka `class Acceptor;`) is sufficient. Hence, you can break the cyclic `#include`s by including `Visitor` in `Acceptor` but not vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Visitor` an incomplete type of `Acceptor` (aka `class Acceptor;`) is sufficient. Hence, you can break the cyclic `#include`s by including `Visitor` in `Acceptor` but not vice versa.

To demonstrate this, I made a one-file-[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
class Acceptor;

class Visitor
{
    friend class Acceptor;

    virtual void visit(Acceptor* t) = 0;
};

class Acceptor
{
    void accept(Visitor* v)
    {
        v->visit(this);
    }
};
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b9291d50e6b6e01)

**Note:**

I had to add the `friend class Acceptor` because all member functions of OPs code are `private`. However, even for this the incomplete type `class Acceptor` appears sufficient.

---

With separate files:

File `visitor.h`:

```
#ifndef VISITOR_H
#define VISITOR_H

class Acceptor;

class Visitor
{
    friend class Acceptor;

    virtual void visit(Acceptor* t) = 0;
};

#endif // VISITOR_H
```

File `acceptor.h`:

```
#ifndef ACCEPTOR_H
#define ACCEPTOR_H

#include "visitor.h"

class Acceptor
{
    void accept(Visitor* v)
    {
        v->visit(this);
    }
};

#endif // ACCEPTOR_H
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've just realized that my problem was, that I didn't created a separate .hpp file for the visitor interface.